# Error al instalar netbeans en mi Mac OS

Tags: netbeans-8.2

tengo en mi Mac OS Apache NetBeans 15 ya instalado y debo instalar netbeans 8.2, ya la descargue pero a la hora de instalar me da un error que indica "JDK NO FOUND", que podría ser ya que necesito tener los 2 tanto Apache NetBeans como el netbeans 8.2 y ya lo he intentado todo y no corre, no se que solución podría tener.

Comment: ""Download JDK for Mac". De nada.

Comment: El problema es que el JDK ya esta instalado solo que sigue mostrando el error

Comment: "Configure JDK Path Netbeans Mac".